# Solve $5^{2x-1}-6e^{x-1}+1=0$

Tags: arithmetic

Find $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$5^{2x-1}-6e^{x-1}+1=0$$

I think that is not possible to find an answer, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, there *is* an obvious root coming from the observation that $5+1=6$.

Comment: and, is it possible to calculate the other solution? (the plot shows a negative solution too)

Comment: I don't think the other solution has an elementary description, although it might be possible using the Lambert W function. Numerically it is approximately $-0.775410212890783968$.

Comment: @yemino You can prove that there is one other (negative) solution, and you can approximate it numerically as accurately as needed, but I don't think there is a closed form for it.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+5%5E(2x-1)-6*exp(x-1)%3D-1

Comment: @dxiv you mean $x=1$?

Comment: @user477343 Yes, $\,5^1 - 6 \cdot e^0 + 1 = 0\,$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that you are looking for the zero(s) of function
$$f(x)=5^{2x-1}-6e^{x-1}+1$$ for which
$$f'(x)=2\ 5^{2 x-1} \log (5)-6 e^{x-1}$$
$$f''(x)=4\ 5^{2 x-1} \log ^2(5)-6 e^{x-1}$$ If you notice that the first derivative can write before simplifications as $$f'(x)=6e^{x-1}\left(\exp\left[(2x-1)\log(5)+\log(2)+\log(\log(5))-(x-1)-\log(6) \right]-1 \right)$$  it cancels at $x_*$ (which makes the argument of the exponential term equal to $0$) given by
$$x_*=\frac{\log \left(\frac{15}{ \log (5)}\right)-1}{2 \log (5)-1}\approx 0.555311$$ At this point
$$f(x_*)\approx-1.65127 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x_*)\approx 8.53411$$ So, two roots and one of them is obvious.

For the second one, you need a numerical method such as Newton; but it requires a reasonable starting point. By inspection or graphing, you will notice that the second solution is between $0$ and $-1$ since $f(0)=\frac{6}{5}-\frac{6}{e}\approx -1.00728 $  and $f(-1)=\frac{126}{125}-\frac{6}{e^2}\approx 0.195988$.

So start the iterations using $x_0=-1$ and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & -1.0000000000 \\
 1 & -0.7507336913 \\
 2 & -0.7751463191 \\
 3 & -0.7754101823 \\
 4 & -0.7754102129
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.